# Fancy Header Suppressed on first page of Appendices Environment

Tags: fancyhdr, appendices

I'm trying to get fancy headers on my appendices. The code I've written works on all pages except the first one after the \appendixpage. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

% -- Headers and Footers --
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       % allow headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE, LO]{{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{Desciption}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{Logo}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\footskip = 45pt

\fancypagestyle{appendix}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE,LO]{\MakeUppercase{\rightmark}}
    \fancyfoot[RE,LO]{Description}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{Logo}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
    \footskip = 45pt
    \fancyheadoffset{1.8 cm} 
    \fancyfootoffset{1.8 cm} 
}

% - Appendices - 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\vspace*{3cm}\centering \huge Appendices\vspace*{\fill} \clearpage}

\newcommand{\appsubsection}[1]{% Trying to remove blank page before pdf (can't get headers to work)
    %   \par\refstepcounter{subsection}% Increase subsection counter
    %   \subsectionmark{#1}% Add subsection mark (header)
    %   \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}% Add subsection to ToC
    \subsection{#1}
}

\usepackage{pdfpages}               % insert pdf files into document


\begin{document}
        \pagestyle{fancy}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage

    \section{Main Section}
    \blindtext[1]
    \subsection{Interesting Subsection}
    \blindtext[1]
    \clearpage

    % To get an A
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{A.\arabic{subsection}}

    \pagestyle{appendix}
    \begin{appendices}

        \clearpage
        \subsection{First Appendix}
        \includepdf[scale=0.9, pages=-, offset=.3in -0.5in, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{appendix}}] 
        {sample.pdf}

        \clearpage
        \subsection{Second Appendix}
        \includepdf[scale=0.9, pages=-, offset=.3in -0.5in, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{appendix}}] 
        {sample.pdf}
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
'''
```